# Fibonacci Sequence with Matlab using Loops(Iteration)

Tags: matlab, loops, iteration

How do I write a Fibonacci function in Matlab using loops? Function must have two inputs.

inputs:
1.a number to start the sequence
2.the number of terms to return (must be a positive integer (N))

Output: is a 1xN vector of the Fibonacci sequence.

Conditions: If the initial term is 0 or 1, the second term will be 1. For any other number, the initial term will be repeated for the second number.

Thanks

Comment: "a number to start the sequence".  By definition, the Fibonacci sequence starts with `f0 = 0` and `f1 = 1`.  Can you please clarify what you mean by "a number to start the sequence"?

Comment: For instance, if the two inputs for the function are (0,6), the output should be [0 1 1 2 3 5]. For inputs (4,10), output should be [4 4 8 12 20 32 52 84 136 220].

Comment: What if the two inputs was: `(3,6)`?  Would the output be `[3 4 4 5 6 9]`?

Comment: for (3,6), output should be [3 3 6 9 15 24]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the [Fibonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) is the following:

[image]

The specifications for your function are rather odd, but nonetheless doable.  First you need to check if the initial term is 0 or 1.  If that's the case, the second term will be 1.  If anything else, the first two terms will be exactly the same as the initial term.  You'll require a bunch of `if` statements first.... so something like this:

```
function out = fibonacci(initial_term, N)

    if initial_term == 0 || initial_term == 1
        second_num = 1;
    else
        second_num = initial_term;
    end

    if N == 1
        out = initial_term;
    elseif N == 2
        out = [initial_term second_num];
    else
        out = zeros(1,N);
        out(1:2) = [initial_term second_num];
        for idx = 3 : N
            out(idx) = out(idx-1) + out(idx-2);
        end
    end
end
```

The first `if` statement checks to see if the initial term is either 0 or 1.  If it is, the second number will be 1.  If it isn't, the second number will be the same as the initial term.

Next, we check to see what `N` is.  If it's 1, then just return the initial term.  If it's 2, then return an array of the initial term and second term.  If it's anything larger, then create an output array of size `N` where the first two elements are initialized like in the case of `N = 2`, then we simply loop through and use the Fibonacci recurrence formula to populate each element in the output from index 3 and onwards.

You can also write the `for` loop as a `while` loop as well.  Remember, a `while` loop keeps iterating **until** the `logical` condition that the `while` loop checks becomes `false`.  As such, you would do:

```
out = zeros(1,N);
out(1:2) = [initial_term second_num];
idx = 3;
while idx <= N
    out(idx) = out(idx-1) + out(idx-2);
    idx = idx + 1;
end
```

## Example Calls

```
>> out = fibonacci(3, 6)

out =

     3     3     6     9    15    24

>> out = fibonacci(0, 6)

out =

     0     1     1     2     3     5

>> out = fibonacci(4, 10)

out =

     4     4     8    12    20    32    52    84   136   220
```

Comment: Thank you sir. BTW, what book would you recommend a beginner with no programming experience to learn Matlab?

Comment: Could you please explain the looping part? Do all loops have to be initialized? And how do you arrive at the 'maths' section of the loop? out = zeros(1,N);
        out(1:2) = [initial_term second_num];
        for idx = 3 : N
            out(idx) = out(idx-1) + out(idx-2);
        end

Comment: This is not for homework. I'm just learning to program in Matlab, and started with a book which I read chapter by chapter and try to answer the questions to help my understanding.

Comment: @timrow - Ah I see.  My apologies for making that assumption!

Comment: Now onto your questions: (1) When you are looping with a `for`, you need to define where it starts looping to where it ends.  In this case, I'm starting at `idx = 3`, as the first two items have already been defined.  (2) I first define an array of zeroes that is `N` long.  Then, I place the first two elements in this array to be the initial term and second term.  After that, we start at `index = 3`, then use the Fibonacci formula to do the rest.

Comment: So can you also solve this problem with a while loop? For a while loop, do you also have to initialize where it starts and stops? I'm trying to get the basic format of for and while loops. Thanks.

Comment: You certainly can!  I'll edit my post so you can see this with a `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you. So all while loops need a counter? The for loop already has a counter which is idx = 3 : N , right?

Comment: That depends. While loops are used when you want the loop to run until something happens. For loops run a set number of times but while loops can run an indeterminate amount of times. While loops can of course act as for loops but those are special cases.

Comment: @timrow - There really isn't a book to read. I learned it all on my own!